# Total up even number from 1 to A number that user enter using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display even number from the user input? My code does not reply anything.

[image: the question]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var num;
    var count = 0;
    var result;

    num = Number(prompt("Enter the maksimum number: ", ""));

    document.write("Sum of all even number from 1 to " + num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i += 2) {
      sum += i;
    }

    document.write(sum);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You never initialized `sum`.

Comment: What are the `count` and `result` variables for?

Comment: Maybe change `var count=0` to `var sum=0`

Comment: Also absolutely [never use `document.write`](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919), it's incredibly ancient and incredibly low level and absolutely does not do what you think it does. Use `console.log()` if you just want to see the value, or put it into some on-page element if you want to see it on your page (e.g. add an element to your page, give it an `id` attribute, and then use something like ```document.getElementById(`...`).innerText = theValueYouGot;```. And remember to put your script in its own file, and load it with `<script src="yourfilehere" async defer></script>` instead of inline

Comment: alright, i forgot to initialize. tq @Barmar

Comment: aaaaa i seee. thankyou @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i will improve my codes better thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot declare a variable using `int`. Use `let` or `const` instead.
2. You need to declare and initialize the variable `sum`.

```js
var num;

num = Number(prompt("Enter the maksimum number: ", ""));

document.write("Sum of all even number from 1 to " + num + ": ");
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 2) {
  sum += i;
}

document.write(sum);
```

Comment: Also definitely remove that `document.write` and show them how to do that part properly, as well. No code since 1992 should be showing, let alone advocating (which is what answers on SO do) its use.

Answer (score 2):

JS does not have an `int` type for your loop to work in, if you change that to `let` and change `count` to `sum` to initialise it it works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      var num;
      var sum = 0;
      var result;

      num = Number(prompt("Enter the maksimum number: ", ""));

      document.write("Sum of all even number from 1 to " + num);

      for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
      }

      document.write(sum);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: At the very least remove that `document.write` and show them how to do that part properly, too.